# how to order sequence vectors in R

Tags: r

```
ii <- order(x <- c(1,1,3:1,1:4,3), y <- c(9,9:1), z <- c(2,1:9))
#[1]  6  5  2  1  7  4 10  8  3  9
```

I don't understand how the results came out. 
How does the order function work when there is several vectors like in this case?
Could you explain how the results came out?

Comment: You should not be using `<-` for parameter specification. Use = instead.

Comment: @Dason its possible that `<-` was intended, because order does not have named parameters x,y & z.  Whereas, using `<-` allows assignment of the vectors for subsequent use outside the function.  I agree this is not common practice in R (C programmers use this type of construct more), but its not necessarily wrong if it is intended.

Answer (score 1):

It is the order of the 1st vector

```
x[ii]
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4
```

The subsequent vectors are only used to break ties:  `?order` tells us,
"In the case of ties in the first vector, values in the second are used to break the ties. If the values are still tied, values in the later arguments are used to break the tie " any unresolved ties will be left in their original ordering.

Think of it a bit like a phone directory.  First it orders by surname. Then, if some people share the same surname, it orders them by first name.  If there are more than one, say, John Smith, it sorts them by middle initial (John A. Smith followed by John B. Smith) etc...

Note that order does not sort the vector. Rather, it returns a numeric index showing the positions of the ordered items in the original vector.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way I can make you to understand this: The `order` function arranges the input vectors as rows:

```
cbind(x,y,z)[ii,]
      x y z
 [1,] 1 5 5
 [2,] 1 6 4
 [3,] 1 9 1
 [4,] 1 9 2
 [5,] 2 4 6
 [6,] 2 7 3
 [7,] 3 1 9
 [8,] 3 3 7
 [9,] 3 8 2
[10,] 4 2 8
```

So as you can see, the result given is:

```
 ii [1]  6  5  2  1  7  4 10  8  3  9
```

meaning, the first position should be occupied by the sixth row, the second by the 5th row, the third by the 2nd row.. all the way to the last position which should be occupied by the 9th row... ok

```
cbind(x,y,z)
      x y z
 [1,] 1 9 2
 [2,] 1 9 1
 [3,] 3 8 2
 [4,] 2 7 3
 [5,] 1 6 4
 [6,] 1 5 5
 [7,] 2 4 6
 [8,] 3 3 7
 [9,] 4 2 8
[10,] 3 1 9
```

Now compare this given matrix, and the results obtained above.. Look at the sixth row here it is `1,5,5` But look at the output above, it is the first row.. Look at the 9th row.. here it becomes the tenth row in the obtained results: thus order function tells you which rows should occupy certain positions.. ie sixth row should occupy the first position, fith row occupy 2nd etc etc..